# Is there an elegant way to pass down an argument from function1() down to a function2(), that takes several arguments?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, arguments

I have the following situation:

```
def func1(a = 0, b = 0):
    return a + b**2

def func2(x):
    if x == 'a':
        return func1(a = 2)
    elif x == 'b':
        return func2(b = 2)

print(func2('a'))
```

Is there a way to just pass `a` not as a String and get rid of the if statements?

Comment: In my actual code there would be much more if-statments, that why I am trying to get rid of them.

Comment: chepner's answer is a straight forward solution to your question.  To be honest, though, something doesn't seem right in the overall design (I do appreciate that you provided a simplified problem, by the way, good job on that ).

Comment: I assume the recursive call to `func2` in the `'b'` branch is a typo for `func1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct a dict and use that with the mapping unpacking syntax.

```
def func2(x):
    return func1(**{x: 2})
```

You might still want an `if` statement to verify that the value of `x` is the name of a valid parameter to `func1`. As shown here, a call like `func2('c')` will produce a `TypeError` when attempting to call `func1` using `{'c': 2}`.

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Comment: Elegant indeed.